# ORMlite connect to an existing Sqlite Table Android

Tags: android, ormlite

Is there a way to open a pre populated sqlite database using ORMLite. I am sure there is but then my next question is should I be using the following line of codes?

```
/**
 * This is called when the database is first created. Usually you should call createTable statements here to create
 * the tables that will store your data.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "onCreate");
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Comment.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource , Words.class);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't create database", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to open a pre populated sqlite database using ORMLite.

To use existing databases, you will need to match your current schema precisely for it to work.  You could also increase your database version and use the `onUpgrade(...)` method to tweak the database to have it match your ORMLite entities.

> I am sure there is but then my next question is should I be using the following line of codes?

The `onCreate(...)` method is called to create new tables if they don't yet exist. To open up *existing* database (like your subject mentions), the `onCreate(...)` method will not be called.